# Why does my jqueryUI autocomplete show at top left corner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am making a ASP.net core application with bootstrap 4, i want to use the jquery UI autocomplete function to autocomplete using a database. i got it all working but the autocomplete is showing up at the top left corner of my screen for some reason?

This is my Js snippet:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Machine").autocomplete({
            source: "/repair/Search",

        });
    });
```

and this is the result:
[image]

i want it to appear just below the textfield like it is supposed to be. ive tried .position tags in the code but i cant get it to work.

Can it have anything to do with using bootstrap?

Comment: Check the CSS for the result section.

Comment: Will you include your full view code? I might need the layout as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing to jquery 1.12.4 and jquery ui 1.12.1 fixed the issue for some reason